# Does this translate to "good job?"

Tags: translation

"Kimashita" is the past tense of "to come". But it seems like in this situation, よくて きました, kimashita means you did, or you were? What am I missing in this case?

Answer (score 5):

You are either misreading it, or reading a typo.  It should be よく**で**きました (parsed as よく・できました), which indeed means "good job" or "well done".